# What is the difference between _url and _path while using the routes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

When we define routes in `routes.rb` using the name like `map.some_link`.We can use the link in two ways- `some_link_url`, `some_link_path`.

- What are the differences between the two?
- Which is more secure to be used?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

I had the same question and I wrote [a small post about this in my blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20110227231430/https://amiridis.net/posts/11)

The reason is summarized here (I found this on a forum):

> *_path are for views because ahrefs are implicitly linked to the current URL. So it’d be a waste of bytes to repeat it over and over. In the controller, though, *_url is needed for redirect_to because the HTTP specification mandates that the Location: header in 3xx redirects is a complete URL.

[Here is another explanation](https://www.viget.com/articles/rails-named-routes-path-vs-url/) which says it depends on whether we need to use an absolute URI when linking to an SSL site from a non-SSL site, and vice versa.

What I have read so far, doesn't suggest that any of them is more secure than the other. It really comes down to what is the "proper" usage.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Found it useful. So in the controllers we use "_url" while in the views we can use "_path" though "_url" can still be used there as well.

Comment: You don't need to use *_url for controllers, path will work just as well. You should only use `_url` when displaying the route to outside sources.

Comment: To clarify some more: the `_path` output will work just as well for the `Location` header in a Redirect. The browser will interpret that as a relative-to-root redirect.

Comment: The quote in the answer is incorrect. `_path` works in controllers.

Comment: The URL to your blog post is 404'ing. Can you update the link?

Comment: Thanks @jshah! I have found the long lost page in the web archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20110227231430/https://amiridis.net/posts/11. I will move it back to my current blog, and update the URL. While doing that, I will try to refresh my answer to include some of the comments in here, but also see if there's a newer take on this.

Comment: I think the answer from @ponzao is more succinct and straightforward.

Answer (score 90):

`path` is relative while `url` is absolute.

Comment: Rather succinct. I like succinct. ;) +1

Comment: Perfect. The usage of _url is required in controller(server-side) and _path are engouh in the view(browser-end).

Comment: Short, concise answer +1

Answer (score 42):

An example of the difference for a resource called "user":

```
users_url # => http://localhost:3000/users
users_path  # => /users
```

Answer (score 2):

Same answer as Petros, except that [modern browsers handle relative redirects just fine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#Using_server-side_scripting_for_redirection). (I'd comment on his answer, but I can't yet.)

Answer (score 1):

By secure if you mean not exposing all the data passed, then _path is better as it generates a relative  url, something like '/login' but _path would give 'http://localhost:3000/login'. Please refer to this blog post i found sometime back regarding the same. [When _url is better than _path](http://blog.theagiledeveloper.com/when-url-is-better-then-path)

Comment: I'm afraid this is incorrect. Using _path for security reasons doesn't provide any security. This would be the same as saying that the IP address of a web server should be kept secret, when a simple DNS request reveals this information.

Comment: Likewise, with the example given above regarding hiding the host and port "localhost:3000" for security, is incorrect. Discovering this information is simple using a software network scanning tool, widely available.

Answer (score 1):

_url will give the entire path. As it contains the domain name and protocol, you can use it for eg. to send email or redirecting to another domain, etc.

_path will return the path which is after '/' without domain,protocol etc. So you can use it every now and then(I guess), where you don't require details of domain.

Answer (score -1):

The `_url` helper generates a string containing the entire URL, while the `_path` helper generates a string containing the relative path from the root of the application, e.g.:

```
photos_url  # => "http://www.example.com/photos"
photos_path # => "/photos"
```

As per [Rails Guides - Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3/routing.html#urls-and-paths).