# Rails 3 - Nested Resources - Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, nested

I'm having issues with my destroy method on a nested source Product, that is tied to Orders.

After attempting to destroy an item, I'm redirecting users to my order_products_url. I receive the following routing error:

```
No route matches "/orders/1/products"
```

My destroy method looks like this:

```
def destroy
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @order = Order.find(params[:order_id])
    @product.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(order_products_url) }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
end
```

And in routes.rb:

```
resources :orders do
    resources :products, :controller => "products"    
  end
```

The reason why this is confusing me, is for my update method for products, I'm properly redirecting users to the order_products_url without issue. I don't understand why it works there but not here.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`order_products_url` expects a parameter to be passed - either the order id, or the order object itself.  Without this, it won't work properly.  So using your code above:

```
def destroy
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @order = Order.find(params[:order_id])
    @product.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(order_products_url(@order) }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
end
```

As a side note, you can shorten your routes a little:

```
resources :orders do
  resources :products
end
```

Specifying the controller is redundant when it's named as Rails expects.  I hope this helps!

**UPDATE:** I've added a link to my article about routing in Rails 3, with downloadable code samples.  I updated it with a paragraph that explains named routes, in the "Things You Should Know" section:

[Routing in Ruby on Rails 3](http://kconrails.com/2010/12/02/routing-in-ruby-on-rails-3/#things_you_should_know)

Comment: Sweet,thanks for the help. After correcting this, I found an issue with my view, where I've now corrected it to where using a delete method on my order_product_path rather than before where I was trying to delete just my @product. I appreciate the help, I really do.

Comment: I'm glad it helped!  If you want more info, I added a link to a blog post I did a while back.  Good luck!

Comment: Also helpful to note is that you include @order in the redirect route -- order_products_url(@order) -- because you need to tell Rails which specific product index you want to show (i.e. the index of products nested under that specific order, not some other order).

Answer (score 3):

Don't you need to redirect to order_products_url(@order)?

Answer (score 1):

you should be using orer_products_path (not url). If you go to the root of your app and type,

```
rake routes
```

that will give you a list of all named routes. You need to append _path to them though (returns the string representation). This is a handy little trick for figuring out named routes.

Now to your real question - of course it doesn't exist! You just deleted it! You are destroying the product instead of the product from the order!

Comment: Both suffixes (_path and _url) work in this instance, it's the missing parameter that is causing the issue.

Comment: Hey Seth, thanks for to help. rake routes was very helping my solve another problem I created once I found my issue from not passing an arguement(doh). For a test, I tried using both _path and _url - both worked. I'm just curious what's the difference between the two?

Comment: _path is relative, _url is absolute http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350539/what-is-the-difference-between-url-and-path-while-using-the-routes-in-rails