# How to get a resource url in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple posing app. How can I get a post url from it's model and pass it to Bitly shortener? (replace http://www.google.com with post url)

It's probably something like

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.posts_path(self...)
```

-

```
class TwitterWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(title, url)
    tweet("#{title} #{url}")
  end
end
```

-

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Tweets
  extend FriendlyId

  after_create :post_to_twitter

.....

  private

  def post_to_twitter
    title = self.title[0..120]
    url = Bitly.client.shorten("http://www.google.com").short_url
    TwitterWorker.perform_async(title, url)
  end

end
```

-

I used to have this code in model

```
 # tweet("#{title[0..120]} #{ Bitly.client.shorten('http://www.google.com').short_url}")
```

---

**UP
I ended up doing the following.**

Since I have a few models that can make postings, I slightly refactored post_to_tweeter meth

**worker**

```
class TwitterWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  include Tweets
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  def perform(message, slug)
    url = Bitly.client.shorten(post_url(slug, host: ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host])).short_url
    tweet("#{message} #{url}")
  end
end
```

**model**

```
after_create :post_to_twitter

def post_to_twitter
  message = "#{self.title[0..120]}"
  TwitterWorker.perform_async(message, self.slug)
end
```

Comment: The models shouldn't know anything about urls. Move your method somewhere else, like an helper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can include the url
helpers in models (though it
normally is not the best way of
dealing with things)

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Rails.application.routes.   url_helpers
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the model IDs in the URL, you can use the code below.  However, I like to use the obfuscate_id and/or friendly_id gems to prevent users from knowing how many records are in the database.

Model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

...

private

  def post_to_twitter
    title = self.title[0..120]
    TwitterWorker.perform_async(title, self.id)
  end
end
```

Twitter Worker:

```
class TwitterWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(title, post_id)
    tweet("#{title} Bitly.client.shorten(post_url(#{post_id})).short_url) 
  end
end
```

This will set the url to http://localhost.com/post/123 if 123 is the post id.

To set what your website is in staging and production enviroments, here's a quick read - [How does rails 4 generate _url and _path helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24756784/how-does-rails-4-generate-url-and-path-helpers).

P.S. You can also use the post_url trick for including the absolute URLS in emails.

Comment: If I just use post_url it doesn't work. I can get path by using Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.post_path(slug). 
posts/post_name. Post_url gives Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true

Comment: Just remembered that you need to include this in the model but you don't need to for controllers, views and mailers: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html