# Rails 4 wrong number of arguments (1 for 2) error for update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am sure it is something small I am not seeing, but I am getting this wrong number of arguments (1 for 2) when I try to update information via a form, in rails 4.

here is my controller action:

```
def update
    @lion = Lion.find(params[:id])
    @lion = Lion.update(lion_params)
    redirect_to lion(@lion)
end
```

and here are the lion_params in the private method for that controller

```
def lion_params
     params.require(:lion).permit(:name, :about, :weight, :health, :health_notes, :photo_url, :trainer_id)
end
```

All the information is present in the form, so I am not quite sure where this error is coming from.

Comment: I have a feeling you meant `@lion.update(lion_params)` and not `@lion = Lion.update(lion_params)`

Comment: on my. I don't know what's worse, making the silly mistake or looking at it so many times and not catching it. lol. thanks for the fresh set of eyes!! :)

Comment: As an off topic comment, when writing Ruby code you will probably want to stick with a 2 space indentation. That is what is used within the Ruby community.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out as well, I do want to follow convention and best-practice :)

Answer (score 3):

You want to use `update_attributes` on `@lion`, not `update:

```
# The bang `!` is used to raise in case of validation errors
@lion.update_attributes!(lion_params)
```

Check [this article](https://priyankapathak.wordpress.com/2010/08/21/difference-between-active-record-methods-update-update_all-update_attribute-update_attributes/) which explains all the differences between update, update_all, update_attribute, update_attributes

Also ensure your last line is `redirect_to lion_url(@lion)` (`lion()` doesn't exist), it's important to use `_url` method because it follows [HTTP specifications](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2350837/312907)

Comment: thank you :) Justin Wood found the error (he responded in a comment however so I couldn't mark it as answered), but I do appreciate the link and will definitely be checking out update_attributes!